# How to put two children of Kendo grid hierarchy into tab?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-grid

I have one parent table and two child tables in hierarchy. What I want is to have a design that the child table was in seperate tab.

This is the sample of what I've already tried. https://dojo.telerik.com/ubiZewAh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the person who down voted was maybe looking for more info.  If I understand correctly you want each table within it's own tab.  Does not appear you are using bootstrap.  However, since you are in control of the template that is used for the data you will need to provide this functionality yourself. Upon clicking the arrow the data will be fetched.  So you will need to add a tab structure and default the first table as shown and all others as hidden. You almost have it but you need to visually show some tabs on the screen.  See HTML below for how your template should be set up. I will leave it up to you to style everything.  I am just going to give you functionality.

```
<div id="detail-template" class="template-container">
    <div class="tabs">
       <div class="tab" data-tab-for="evidence">Evidence</div>
       <div class="tab" data-tab-for="notes">Notes</div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class='tab-pane' id="evidence">
        <div class="evidence-grid"></div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class='tab-pane' id="notes" style="display:none'>
        <div class="notes-grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>

//Jquery
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#case-grid').on('click', '.tab', tabClicked);
});

function tabClicked(e) {
    var elClicked = $(this);

    //Hide all panes then show correct one
    $('.tab-pane').hide();
    var paneToShow = elClicked.data('tabFor');
    $('#' + paneToShow).show();

    //I would instead use the active flag on the tabs themselves
    //Style them however you want
    //Take the style off all tabs then add to correct one.
    $('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

If you want to save yourself some trips to the backend when you do not need to I would not load the child grids upon loading of the grid init.  I would instead on click of the tab.  Find the grid within the tab pane selected and fetch the data at that time.  for example if the user never looks at the notes tab then there is no reason to go get it.  Unless you just want to prerender it with the expectation they will.  Also, you may want to change the class references I have within the tabClicked function to be relative to be sure we are only updating the correct one.  For example,

Change 
    $('.tab-pane').hide();
To
    $('.tab-pane', elClicked.closest('.template-container')).hide();

After looking over my answer you may want to use class references everywhere since the template is used multiple times.  I didn't look at the generated code of kendo.  However, upon closing the row the DOM of the child grids are not removed. Therefore, with jquery it will modify all with the same id.  So for example your panes have id of evidence and notes.  You may want to make these data attributes and then just like I said above reference them relative to the clicked element(tab)